# why `refetch` in "useLazyQuery" of Apollo-client, doesn't causing component re-rendering or update `data` in next js?

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo-client

I created a react-hook for `useLazyQuery`.

```
export const useCustomQuery = ({ query, variables, hasAuth, hasVar }: HookOptions) => {
  let options = {};
  if (Boolean(hasVar) && Boolean(variables)) {
    options = {
      ...options,
      variables,
    };
  }

  if (Boolean(hasAuth)) {
     let token = "";
     if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
       token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken") || "";
     }
    options = {
      ...options,
      context: {
        headers: {
          authorization: token,
        },
      },
    };
  }

  const [QueryFunc, { loading, error, data, refetch, called, networkStatus }] =
    useLazyQuery(query, options);

  return { QueryFunc, loading, error, data, refetch, called, networkStatus };
};
```

now I'm calling this hook in my context

```
const {
    QueryFunc: getUserAction,
    loading: userLoadingScreen,
    data: userData,
    refetch: refetchUserAction,
    called,
    error: userError,
    networkStatus,
  } = useCustomQuery({
    query: GET_USER,
    hasAuth: true,
  });
```

callilng `getUser` query, on button click:

```
 getUserAction({
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        nextFetchPolicy: "network-only"
 });
```

After calling getUserAction on a button click, **it causing the rerender, hence `userData` and `userLoadingScreen` values are changing as expected**.

however, when I called  `refetchUserAction` it doing the network request, **but not updating `userData` and `userLoadingScreen` state**

I created the apollo client something like this:

```
const createApolloClient = () => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === "undefined",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    connectToDevTools: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
    link: createUploadLink({
      uri: "url",
      headers: { "Apollo-Require-Preflight": "true" },
    }),
  });
};
```

calling the apollo-client on `_app.tsx` :

```
function MyApp({ Component, ...rest }: AppProps) {
 const client = createApolloClient();

 return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AuthProvider> // this is the context where i'm calling the `getUser` query
              // other routes
        </AuthProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

how can I solve this or what am I doing wrong here?
And one more thing, if I change route the `getUser` query, which present in the context, calling automatically and updating `data` and `loading` state. but on calling `refetch`, it just doing the network call, not re-rendering component or changing `data` state.